# Path integral representation for the Supersymmetric Index

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, path-integral, sigma-models

The Supersymmetric Index is known to have the following path integral representation (*Mirror Symmetry,* equation (10.126)):$$Tr[(-1)^Fexp(-\beta H)]=\int_{PBCs}DxD\bar{\psi}D{\psi}\exp(-S_E)\tag{10.126}$$
Can someone please guide as to where I may find an introductory discussion regarding the derivation of this result? For very simple and specific models, this can be done, but how does one prove this in general?

Comment: I think the derivation of the formula is well-explained in the Mirror Symmetry book you mentioned.